# Create a dynamic row of UITextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I would like some help creating a dynamic row of `UITextfields`, I have been trying to do it myself with some success but mostly failure.

I set a number of rows between 1 - 13 and I would like to create `UITextfields` that fit inside the width of an iPhone frame width evenly spaced with an even gap to the left and right.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
- (void) displayViews {
    // add scrollview
    htmlContainerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 60.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 293.0)];
    NSInteger viewcount = [axisString integerValue];
    color = 200;

    for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {
        color = color + 20;
        NSLog(@"%f", color);
        CGFloat y = i * 91;
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,self.view.frame.size.width, 90.0)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:(1.0/i)];;
        [htmlContainerScrollView addSubview:view];

        int cutCount = [cutsString integerValue];
        int positions = (self.view.frame.size.width/cutCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < cutCount; i++) {
            //first one
            UITextField *cutField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((positions*i)+(20/2), 25, 20, 20)];
            cutField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
            cutField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
            cutField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [view addSubview:cutField];
        }       
    }
    htmlContainerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 91 *viewcount);
    [self.view addSubview:htmlContainerScrollView];
}
```

The biggest problem with mine is that it does not evenly space them; they are always to the left.

Comment: I would suggest that you use layout constraints instead of setting frames. If you give your text fields the same spacing constraint to the left and right side of the view, it will work well.

Comment: but i will have a dynamic number of textfields? how would that work?

Comment: It would be similar to what you have now -- in a loop, create the text fields, add them to your view, then add the constraints to that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `cutField`'s frame **x** coordinate value calculation from

- `(positions*i)+(20/2)`
  to
- `((positions*i)-(20/2)+(positions/2))`.

that should do the trick.

---

it's just a matter of the x coordinate calculation and i am sure there is room to optimize that a bit.